# Create a variable in R that indicates whether numeric "subgroup" rows sum to "total" rows by group

Tags: r, data-wrangling, rowwise

I would like to be able to create a logical variable that indicates, for a specific category, whether the counts of a set of subgroup rows (i.e., A, B, C in the 'group' variable) sum to the same value as my 'All' / overall group rows.

My data look like:

```
group = c("All", "A", "B", "C", "All", "A", "B", "C")
category = c("music", "music", "music", "music", "movies", "movies", "movies", "movies")
count = c(120, 15, 75, 30, 250, 36, 28, 72)

data <- data.frame(cbind(group, category, count))
```

What I would like is the addition of the "sum_to_all" column, as in:

```
sum_to_all = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)

data <- data.frame(cbind(group, category, count, sum_to_all))
```

In this case, the "count" variable subgroups "A", "B" and "C" sum to the count in the "All" group (TRUE) for the music category, but not for the movies (FALSE) category.

I know that I could reshape the dataset to wide in which each group would have it's own "count" column and compare the columns, but I'm wondering if there's a simple row-wise solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As an aside `data.frame(cbind(group, category, count))` converts all your numbers to text because of `cbind` which makes a `matrix` first. You can skip that part and just do `data.frame(group, category, count)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'category' and create the 'sum_to_all' by comparing the `sum` of 'count' not including the first observation with the `first` observation

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(category) %>%
    mutate(sum_to_all = sum(count[-1]) == first(count)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  group category count sum_to_all
#  <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <lgl>     
#1 All   music      120 TRUE      
#2 A     music       15 TRUE      
#3 B     music       75 TRUE      
#4 C     music       30 TRUE      
#5 All   movies     250 FALSE     
#6 A     movies      36 FALSE     
#7 B     movies      28 FALSE     
#8 C     movies      72 FALSE
```

NOTE: Here we assume 'All' 'group' as the `first` element. If it is not always the case, either do an `arrange` or subset with `==`

```
data %>%
    group_by(category) %>%
    mutate(sum_to_all = sum(count[group != 'All']) ==count[group == 'All']) %>%
    ungroup
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(group, category, count)
```

Comment: Thank you. If I were to want only a sum of groups A and B for this comparison, would you know how I might exclude both "All" AND "C"?

Comment: @mkpcr In that case case you can use `[! group %in% c("All", "C")]` and `[group %in% c("All", "C")]` to replace in the second solution